# android-Taking json from https web service

Tags: android, web-services, rest

I can get my json from a http web server and it works fine but now I have to take it from a https server but it couldn't get the json file.So what can be the problem? If problem is https server how can I solve it ? Any help would be apprecaited.

Comment: What did you do so far.Post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        String reply = "";
        BufferedReader inStream = null; 
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
            inStream = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";

            while ((line = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            inStream.close();

            reply = buffer.toString();  

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle Execptions
        }
```